# I want to save my Battery

Tags: power-management, laptop, battery

My battery power is dropping rapidly. I have already install the TLP and for every boot up I keep my tlp in battery mode. But still it is unsolved.

Comment: Please update your question with the following info: CPU, GPU, laptop model? If you prefer you can submit a screenshot of the "about" tab on settings. This info can be helpful to determine if any extra `tlp` setup can help you to save more battery.

Comment: What is the output of `$ systemctl status tlp`?

Comment: Please update this question with the information you submitted [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1205541/how-can-i-save-my-battery).

Comment: The problem could be the GPU. What drivers does it use? You can check it on **Software & Updates**, **Additional Drivers** tab.